# generating CSR for quickbook application registration process

Tags: csr

We are integrating our web application with Quick book. We are using hosted model. We need to register our web application. However we are not able to do so as it ask for CSR key. But we have no idea from where we will get this?

Any answers?

Answer (score 0):

There are detailed instructions for getting QuickBooks Online Edition applications registered on this wiki page: [QuickBooks Online Edition integration wiki](http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_online_edition)

There are detailed instructions for QuickBooks Merchant Service on this wiki page: [QuickBooks Merchant Service integration wiki](http://wiki.consolibyte.com/wiki/doku.php/quickbooks_qbms_integration)

You didn't really give many details in your question, but the process is basically:

1. Fill in the initial application registration information
2. Create a CSR (certificate signing request) on your server using these commands:

   openssl genrsa -out host.key 1024

   openssl req -new -nodes -key host.key -out host.csr
3. Save the signed certificate Intuit sends back to you for use in your outgoing requests.

If you need more help you'll have to post where exactly you're stuck in the process and what you've done so far.